# Get bound data from container control with UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, winui-3

I am writing this app where I use the `NavigationView` control, and I would like to not have static menu items in it, so I bind this control's `MenuItemsSource` property to list of menu item objects described with class like this:

```cs
public sealed class MenuItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

I then template this data using `DataTemplate`:

```xml
<DataTemplate x:DataType="menu:MenuItem">
    <NavigationViewItem Content="{x:Bind Name}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Finally, I would like to react to `ItemInvoked` events, e.g. for navigation. For that I need to get the `MenuItem` instance that was bound to this specific `NavigationViewItem`. Alas, in event args there is only the container control itself, not the data it was made from. The closest I was to reaching the desired functionality is when binding the `DataContext` property of `NavigationViewItem` to bound data, like this:

```xml
<DataTemplate x:DataType="menu:MenuItem">
    <NavigationViewItem Content="{x:Bind Name}" DataContext={x:Bind} />
</DataTemplate>
```

But it seems slightly wrong, although I cannot think of better solution. Could someone help me out?

**Update**: I found the method `XamlBindingHelper.GetDataTemplateComponent` which returns some dynamic object with properties, and one of them is exactly the data I am after. If it is present there, why aren't there any helper methods to reliably get it back?

[image: Getting to the data bound to container]

Comment: Why does using the DataContext seem wrong that's your VM in MVVM? Also, why not set the Tag property and use that for your navigation logic like in the example in the docs?

Comment: Matching container control back to data it was created from through the `Tag` property seems artificial and unnecessary, since the data ought to be somewhere around. I found that if I use `XamlBindingHelper.GetDataTemplateComponent` on the container I can get the object with private properties, where one of them is exactly my data class, I just can't get it since it is private.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting using the Tag to find the data, rather to control your navigation. Not sure what data you'd need to string along. In any case, isn't the NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs.InvokedItem the instance of the MenuItem class that you want?

Comment: @HasaniH no, it's not, it's the string that I bind to `NavigationViewItem.Content` property.

Answer (score 0):

> But it seems slightly wrong, although I cannot think of better solution. Could someone help me out?

Actually, in the `ItemInvoked` event, you could get an **InvokedItem** object directly from the **NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs**.  And the **InvokedItem** object is the data that you used to bind to the `NavigationViewMenuItem`.

For example,if I have `NavigationViewMenuItem` template a like this:

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="NavigationViewMenuItem" x:DataType="local:TestMenuItem">
        <NavigationViewItem Content="{x:Bind ItemName}" />
    </DataTemplate>
```

And the **TestMenuItem** object like this:

```
public class TestMenuItem 
{
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the `ItemInvoked` event, I could get get the value of the `ItemName` property like this:

```
  private void NavigationView_ItemInvoked(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs args)
    {
        // directly get the item value
        var item = args.InvokedItem as string;

        switch (item) 
        {
            case "AAA":
                ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(AAAPage));
                break;
            case "BBB":
                ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(BBBPage));
                break;
            case "CCC":
                ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(CCCPage));
                break;

        };
    }
```

Comment: Actually, yes, I can see the `Item` property, and it is whatever I bind to Content property of the navigation menu item. What I am trying to do is to decouple data from presentation, so my menu item class, besides the display text, also contains the type of page I am willing to navigate to, but I can't get to it from event handler unless I bind it to some control's property.

Comment: @kosmakoff I'm confused. You could get the `MenuItem` object for the invoked item, right? It contains the data that you could use to check which item you are clicking. Then what else do you want to get?

Comment: Li no, in `Item` there is a string that I bind from `ItemName` property of menu item class (not to be confused with UI menu item). Summarizing, nowhere in events args I can get the object that was used to render the template with `NavigationViewItem`. Because of that I would have to look up my original data class using tag, like you showed in your example. But I want to have the menu items dynamic, therefore I need to introduce some artificial key property to menu items and bind it `Tag` on UI for further lookup. All because there is no other way.

Answer (score 0):

Your `MenuItemTemplate` should not contain a `NavigationViewItem` container. Replace it with a `TextBlock`:

```
<NavigationView.MenuItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="menu:MenuItem">
        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</NavigationView.MenuItemTemplate>
```

You could then easily get a reference to the `MenuItem` source of the clicked item in the event handler by casting the `InvokedItem` property of the `NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs`:

```
private void OnItemInvoked(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs args)
{
    MenuItem menuItem = args.InvokedItem as MenuItem;
    //access any properties of the clicked MenuItem here, e.g.:
    string name = menuItem.Name;
}
```

Comment: It fixed getting the menu items, but now I can't set the icon on my menu items. The original post code is stripped of many details, but in practice I also set Icon on menu item. Can't set it if I replace menu item with just text box.

Comment: You don't specify an icon in a `DataTemplate`. Use the `MenuItemContainerStyle` property to do that. But please ask a new question if you have another issue. The `MenuItemTemplate` should not contain a `NavigationViewItem`. The control wraps the root element in your template with one for you.

Comment: @kosmakoff: Did you fix this or what's left to your question?